# Feature generation for multi-label classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-engineering, multilabel-classification, multi-output

**Problem statement**

Predict customer's likelihood/propensity to buy multiple category of products from a grocery store give past purchase data (Given a set of users at time , predict whether they will buy products from a category in future i.e +, here  just represents an undefined future time instance). Number of categories are 20 (e,g, dairy, chips, soft drinks etc). A customer can be interested in multiple categories at the same time hence I am treating this a multi-label problem.

I have built per category binary classification models where in the features for the positive class were calculated using the purchase data until their first purchase of the product category (the category for which the binary classifier was built). The negative class had same features calculated until their most recent orders. This dataset has a single row for a single customer, i.e multiple entries for a customer *will not exist*.

The model was trained to therefore predict likelihood of a future purchase. These models have worked well but maintaining 20 different models is pain. I would like to consolidate them into a single multi-label model.

**Features**

For likelihood to buy dairy model some features are like

- promotion of order with snacks
- promotion of order with soft drinks
- promotion of order snacks with promotion
- etc etc

**note:** since we are only calculating +ve class features until a customer's 1st dairy purchase, category=dairy related features will be all 0 as no dairy purchase data will be present (obviously these features are not part of training data).

For likelihood to buy snacks model some features are like

- promotion of order with dairy
- promotion of order with soft drinks
- promotion of order dairy with promotion
- etc etc

**note:** since we are only calculating +ve class features until a customer's 1st snacks purchase, category=snacks related features will be all 0 as no snacks purchase data will be present (obviously these features are not part of training data).

But building a multi label model posses a challenge from a feature generation perspective. I cannot simply combine/concat features from all models because potential data leakage issues and for other obvious reasons.

Let me explain:
As stated above, we generate features for +ve class until their first purchase of a particular category hence for each label in the multi-label setting, feature set will be different, i.e say a customer ABC bought its first dairy product on their 3rd order and a snack product on their 5 order, features used for dairy model will have all snacks features equal to 0 and all dairy features equal to 0 but features related to snacks model will have *non 0* values for all dairy features as customer has bought dairy product prior to their first snacks product purchase. Hence if aggregate or concat features from multiple model (not suggesting that I will) into a format where each customer has only one row of features I will have data leakage I feel as few columns will suggest that dairy was not bought and some will suggest dairy was bought.

**Questions**

1. Do you all feel that this is a genuine problem or I am missing something here ?
2. If the answer to 1 is "yes" then can this problem be structured as multi label problem ? I have seem Amazon blog posts where they say they do almost the exact thing but dont talk about how they built the training dataset.
3. If the answer to 1 and 2 is "yes", then give the problem statement how do you guys recommend I should structure my data for a multi-label setting ?

Thanks a ton !